# Read IMDb cast for a title

Tags: java, imdb

So I am a VERY beginner-level Java developer - really, I am still in the process of learning Java.  Don't have experience or training with other languages yet.

For a purely personal project that no one else would ever see or touch, I am trying to write a program that, given a particular title, will read cast info from IMDb.  I would like to pull the IMDb nm codes for each person in the cast, and, ideally, their names as well (but the nm codes are more important).  (Every person in IMDb has a nm code used in their URL - e.g., http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000620/ is the IMDb page for Mickey Rourke; so his unique IMDb ID is nm0000620.)

I would ultimately like to export that data into a spreadsheet, but I'm not too worried about that step for now.  I will NEVER be building this into any type of web or smartphone interface.  I just want the data, and would like to write a Java program to get it to save me time in looking it up myself, title by title.

I found info on the web about generally reading text from a URL and was playing with that, but hit a wall when testing it.  Then I started Googling specifically about IMDb, and am finding lots of info, but a lot of it is not easy for me to understand or decipher, the newbie that I am.  I have both Eclipse and BlueJ installed and do my work in those.

Now, I fully understand and accept that (1) I may just have to spend more time researching and understanding the available options on my own, from my web search results; and (2) I may need to further my own Java learning and development before I can feasibly finish working on this project.  If that's the case, so be it, I will move on and trudge through, no biggie.

(I also understand that IMDb has its own rules and licenses in place about reading its data.  I will work with some other database (OMDb, or Rotten Tomatoes, or something) if I need to, I just prefer IMDb because that's what I've been using so far (in a more manual way, not in Java).)

However, if there is already some Java code out there somewhere that will get me started and save me hours of work, I would obviously be grateful if anyone can point me to it.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1):

1. [This](http://www.imdb.com/interfaces) link could be useful for you now.
2. Also, take a look [here](http://www.omdbapi.com) , if you want to play with JSON and http requests.I think it fits to your needs :)
3. The last but not the least choice that I personally prefer , is [jmdb](http://www.jmdb.de)

All the above solutions are perfect for your needs, depending which way you want to follow.

Comment: Thanks karvoynistas! I'd already found & looked thru all 3 of those - which may just confirm that I need to just dig in & read and learn more on my own. I think #1 offers data files I could save to my PC but I'd prefer to read real time data from the website.  (Again, I'll take what I can get, so if that's the best solution, I'll do it.) It looks like #2 doesn't yet offer cast info for a title. I think #3 is a standalone app that also uses data files.

Comment: What I really want is Java code I can copy & paste into my program to read the cast details so I can build the rest of my program using that data. But maybe it's just not that simple.

Comment: Check this out http://en.sourceforge.jp/projects/sfnet_imdbcrawler/downloads/imdb/movieAttributes/ImdbMovieAttributes.java/  its an imdb crowler